# Ellipse Locus Feynman approach

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, conic-sections

The following seeks to identify which  alternate accelerations act ( gravitational, tangential, centrifugal) in *Feynman's  dynamics scheme* leading to the same position of planet once again at the Newton classical position.

Request you to please help in drawing a new *force diagram* including the perpendicular bisector accelerations leading to this alternate dynamic derivation.

[Feynman's Lost nb (30 - 50 sec)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdIjYBtnvZU&list=LLAvD2S26El96ymbE_kNOOyA&index=367)

[image]

A *geometrical verification* is made below using elimination by p- discriminant method

A variable point P (in above rough sketch) on a circle radius $2a$  centered at origin  and focal point F $(2c,0)$. Finding envelope of perpendicular bisectors of PF.

$$ ( 2a\ \cos t, 2a \sin t), (c+ a \cos t,a \sin t)$$

Equation of perpendicular bisector through center point $Q$of $PF$.

$$    \dfrac{a \cos t- c}{a\sin t}= \dfrac{y-a \sin t}{x-c- a \cos t} \tag1  $$

Let $ a^2-c^2=b^2.$ Cross multiplying and simplifying

$$ \dfrac{b^2+x \cos t}{a}= ( x \cos t+ y \sin t) \tag 2$$

Using p-discriminant method partially differentiate with respect to $t$

$$ \tan  t = \dfrac{y}{x} \tag 3 $$

Plug into (1) using

$$ x = r \cos t, y=r  \sin \theta , p= b^2/a , r= \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \; e = c/a \tag4 $$

we arrive at

$$ e x +p=r \to \dfrac{1}{r}=\dfrac{1- e \cos \theta}{p}. \tag5 $$

Comment: I don't understand your request: there is no "new force diagram including the perpendicular bisector accelerations", force is of course given by the usual gravitational law. The trick explained in the video is used to show that the orbit is a conic section.

Comment: Is it just a property of conics not related to orbital  dynamics?

Comment: Dynamics enters only in the determination of the hodograph, which turns out to be a circle. See here: http://mysite.du.edu/~jcalvert/phys/hodo.htm#Orbi